# Pantheon Terminal Ubuntu 15.04 - GTK3 Title/Header Bar Issue

Tags: unity, 15.04, gtk3, elementary, pantheon

I heard Pantheon Terminal is one of the most intuitive terminals to use and thought I would give it a go on vanilla Ubuntu Vivid 15.04.

I installed it (0.3.1.2+r736+pkg36) from the following commands (using their release specifically for Vivid, although I understand it's mainly intended for use in the Elementary OS fork of Ubuntu):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-terminal
```

It all works really nicely apart from three window issues:

[image: bugs]

1. The title bar is not using the Ubuntu window theme.
2. When the window is maximized, the title bar is shown twice, as seen in the screen shot below.
3. In both maximized and unmaximized states, the title bar is transparent (my wallpaper is purple). This is really confusing when you have a window behind the terminal which shows its title bar in Pantheon's place.

Is anyone aware of any workarounds to fix these issues and if they should be reported on Launchpad?

If I were to switch to using the Elementary desktop environment then it would likely work better, but Elementary DE is incompatible with 15.04 and I would prefer to carry on using the Pantheon terminal in vanilla Ubuntu if possible.

Comment: Since this terminal emulator is focused on the gnome desktop, there is nothing wrong with it...it's just using gnome header bar. https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/GnomeGoals/HeaderBars

Comment: I mean gnome header bar. https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/GnomeGoals/HeaderBars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @xangua pointed out, pantheon-terminal is using the new "header bars" client-side decoration component of GTK. Unity in Ubuntu 15.04 doesn't appear to support this. An unofficial workaround for the issue I experienced is to disable client-side decorations for the affected app:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk3-nocsd
gksu nano /usr/share/applications/pantheon-terminal.desktop
```

Edit your `Exec=` line to look like below:

```
Exec=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/gtk3-nocsd/gtk3-nocsd.so pantheon-terminal
```

Now the pantheon-terminal header bar is no longer transparent in Unity :)

**EDIT: I now advise against the current version of the gtk-nocsd workaround (0-1+git20140824), as it causes the GUI parts of some programs such as hplip-3.15.6 to segfault when run from the pantheon-terminal. The nocsd authors appear to be working on some fixes for this however: https://github.com/PCMan/gtk3-nocsd/pull/8**